# White Space Issue

Tags: css, whitespace

For some reason I can not see how to delete this large gap in between my title and the details. I inspected different areas and cant see any padding being added.  I marked out the area in red that I would like to remove. The only tricky part is that I would like to delete this spacing without it affecting the page once you click on "heavy duty mechanic"

I apologize for the easy question but have tried and cant seem to get it but must be over looking something.

http://jobspark.ca/job-listings/

[image]

Comment: `-1` for question with no code.

Comment: He linked the site...

Comment: The code on the site can change which is why it's good to have a static copy here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.article-meta` rule includes `margin-top:24px`, is this maybe what's causing it?

Additionaly, the `h1` rule specifies a `margin-bottom:24px`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem relies on a margin being added to all the headings:

```
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {margin: 0 0 24px}
```

adding a margin to the bottom of your title (as well as your subtitles, etc).

By removing that value (24px) you affect the page when you click on "heavy duty mechanic". Maybe you could try removing the margin bottom on the h1 and adding a margin a top to the subtitle in "heavy duty mechanic" ("About this opportunity").

Answer (score 0):

Your "footer" element has 24px margin-top. This is the structure of your HTML:

```
<header>
(space because the header is 45px)
<div class="body">
(space because the footer has margin-top: 24px)
<footer>
```

On the page produced by clicking "Heavy Duty", the footer and it's margin-top spacing is still there, it's just after that long chunk of text in your "body" div. In the link you gave, your body is empty, so you're seeing that margin-top space right below your header. You're going to need to add CSS/Javascript for specifically this page if you want to overwrite the margin-top. If you're using Chrome, right click your element, click Inspect Element, and on the right click Computed Style and you'll see the margin-top

Answer (score 0):

Change the `margin-bottom` of `h1` and `margin-top` of `footer`. Instead of removing one's margin I would say, reduce both to half, maybe?

```
article h1 {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

article footer {
    margin-top: 12px;
}
```